# Transform a XML whose elements have several attributes and use one attribute to create new elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Suppose you want to transform this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package id="album">
    <concept id="tracknumber" value="18"></concept>
    <concept id="songtitle" value="Multi Love"></concept>
    <concept id="band" value="Unknown Mortal Orchestra"></concept>
</package>
```

into this XML:

```
<package>
    <tracknumber>18</tracknumber>
    <songtitle>Multi Love</songtitle>
    <band>Unknown Mortal Orchestra</band>
</package>
```

This is the starting point XSLT to transform the source XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="package[@id='album']">
            <package>
                <tracknumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concept[@id='tracknumber']" />
                </tracknumber>
                <songtitle>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concept[@id='songtitle']" />
                </songtitle>
                <band>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concept[@id='band']" />
                </band>
            </package>

        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

It seems to be tricky to get the "value" portion of the XML attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a dynamic XSLT solution without explicit value criteria in case XML contains many `<concept>` tags:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="package[@id='album']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="concept" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="concept">            
        <xsl:element name="{@id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </xsl:element>            
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's a great answer! I simplified this example to make it easier to understand. In real life, the result is a bit trickier, having some complex elements that follow no specific logic other than client needs.

Comment: Awesome! I thought it was simplified. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the XSLT to use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="package[@id='album']">
    <package>
        <tracknumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="concept[@id='tracknumber']/@value />
        </tracknumber>
        <songtitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="concept[@id='songtitle']/@value" />
        </songtitle>
        <band>
            <xsl:value-of select="concept[@id='band']/@value" />
        </band>
    </package>

   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```